# How can I pass a parameter to ng-click inside an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code in which I am repeating over an array and want to add a functionality that if I click on a row, its data is displayed somewhere else on the same page.

```
<table>
  <button ng-click="console.log('hello')">view</td>
  <div>
    <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:searchText" >
      <td>{{contact.city}}
      </td>
      <td>{{contact.firstName}}</td>
      <td><button ng-click="console.log(contact.id)">view</td>
    </tr>
  </div>
  </table>
```

I can't seem to figure out why none of the ng-click's are working even when I write it to output a simple message to the console.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngClick

Comment: so I added 'ngTouch' here var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngTouch']); do I have to add it somehwere else as well. please let me know

Answer (score 0):

When you call `console.log()` from `ng-click`, it is actually looking for `$scope.console.log()`, which does not exist.  You need to create a function in your controller that takes an input, and then calls the javascript `console.log()` function.

```
$scope.log = function(value){
  console.log(value);
}
```

Then you bind to it like this:

```
<button ng-click="log(contact.id)">
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1P7x5asZsClxEz94vNNp?p=preview)

Comment: I cannot get even get an alert(contact.id) to work and cannot figure out why. HEre is my controller. myApp.controller('contactsController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){
    //get data by ajax call  $scope.contacts=data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
    var showDetails=function(contactId){
        alert(contactId);
    }
}])

Comment: Your controller code is not correct.  I've updated my demo to show retrieving data via `$http`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @Jerrad is right. But if you want to print the whole row data you have to pass the whole `contact` object into the function. And your `HTML` is also not correct.

Working code is here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app>
    <table ng-controller="controller">
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" />
        <div>
            <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:searchText">
                <td>{{contact.city}}
                </td>
                <td>{{contact.firstName}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button ng-click="getRowData(contact)">view</button>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </table>
    <script>
        function controller($scope, $http) {
            $scope.contacts = [
                {'city':'City 1', 'firstName':'Firstname 1'},
                {'city':'City 2', 'firstName':'Firstname 2'},
            ];

            $scope.getRowData = function(data) {
                console.log(data.city+'==='+data.firstName);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```